# fill background color between 2 lines.new in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to fill the background color between these 2 lines and I am getting the following error messages:

line 104: Syntax error at input 'bullEngulfLow'.

I am using the following code.

```
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    fillColor = switch
    bullEngulfOpen > bullEngulfLow => color.green
    => color.silver
linefill.new(bullEngulfOpen, bullEngulfLow, color.new(fillColor, 90))

bullEngulfOpen := line.new(bar_index - 1, resopen[1], bar_index, resopen[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.black)
bullEngulfLow := line.new(bar_index - 1, bullEngulfLowPrice, bar_index, bullEngulfLowPrice, extend=extend.right, color=#01ff00)
```

How do I fill the background color between these 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fill()` function can only fill the space between plots or hlines. If you want to fill space between lines created via `line.new()`, you need to use the functions in the `linefill.*` namespace, [more info here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-now-support-fills-between-line-drawings-28665/).

Comment: thanks, I checked out that page and this is the code I used and I am getting error messages.

Comment: Please ask one question per post (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)). @beeholder's post answers your original question.

Comment: It doesn't work with lines, only with PLOT and HLINES